# MYSQL 1215 Cannot add Foreign Key Constraing

Tags: mysql

Problem is on the bounding table column `GroupDim.FacultyID` and `FacultyDim.FacultyID`, data types are identity  `BIGINT` This data store for OLAP cube wherein Rating_facts stores result of question which i exploring. table without signature `Dim` is transitional and serve for additional data for analysis.Maybe it is needs to divide this table?

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BlockDim;
CREATE TABLE BlockDim (
    BlockKey bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    BlockID bigint NOT NULL,
    BlockName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (BlockKey)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FacultyDim;
CREATE TABLE FacultyDim (
    FacultyKey bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FacultyID bigint NOT NULL,
    FacultyName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (FacultyKey, FacultyID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Group`; 
CREATE TABLE `Group` (
    GroupID bigint NOT NULL,
    FacultyID bigint NOT NULL,
    GroupName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (GroupID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FacultyID) REFERENCES FacultyDim(FacultyID) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Subblock; 
CREATE TABLE Subblock (
    SubblockKey bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SubblockID bigint NOT NULL,
    BlockID bigint NOT NULL,
    SubblockName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SubblockKey)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Paragraph; 
CREATE TABLE Paragraph (
    ParagraphKey bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ParagraphID bigint NOT NULL,
    SubblockID bigint NOT NULL,
    ParagraphName varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ParagraphKey)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RatingDim; 
CREATE TABLE RatingDim (
    RatingKey bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RatingID bigint NOT NULL,
    ParagraphID bigint NOT NULL,
    Score double NOT NULL,
    StageOfApprove int NOT NULL,
    Comment varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (RatingKey)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TimeDim; 
CREATE TABLE TimeDim (
    TimeKey bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
    DayOfWeek varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `Month` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `Year` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`TimeKey`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Rating_Fact;
CREATE TABLE Rating_Fact (
    TimeKey bigint NOT NULL,
    BlockKey bigint NOT NULL,
    FacultyKey bigint NOT NULL,
    RatingKey bigint NOT NULL,
    PopularBlock bigint NOT NULL,
    AvgFacultyScore bigint NOT NULL,
    StudentsMaxRating bigint NOT NULL,
    StudentsNotApprovedRating bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (TimeKey,BlockKey,FacultyKey,RatingKey),
    FOREIGN KEY (TimeKey) REFERENCES TimeDim(TimeKey),
    FOREIGN KEY (BlockKey) REFERENCES BlockDim(BlockKey),
    FOREIGN KEY (FacultyKey) REFERENCES FacultyDim(FacultyKey),
    FOREIGN KEY (RatingKey) REFERENCES RatingDim(RatingKey)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: The FK must include the whole referenced PK.'

Comment: you can't have a foreign key to _half_ a primary key...it can't guarantee to uniquely identify the parent row based on only one of the fields. That logic ought to be obvious, surely?

Comment: I should also add, it's not clear _why_ you've got a compound key in FacultyDim...if you already have FacultyKey as an auto_increment, then it should always be unique. Why do you need FacultyID as well?? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @jarlh earlier such construction as this works fine, maybe now it is cause FacultyDim have 2 primary Key? As I understand this construction is right? CONSTRAINT GroupDim_fk0 FOREIGN KEY (FacultyID) REFERENCES FacultyDim (FacultyID)

Comment: @Adyson it is for DataAnalysis with POWERBI

Comment: The problem is that the FK has 1 column, but the referenced PK (now) has 2 columns. Must be the same number. But why has FacultyDim  a 2 column PK?

Comment: There doesn't seem to much point in FacultyKey.

Comment: @ТарасДанальченко "it's for powerBI"...so? That's not really the question. Or at least it's too vague an answer. The question is specifically why you need two columns in your key? What practical problem does that solve for you, compared with having just FacultyKey alone as the primary key? It doesn't make a lot of sense the way you've got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have check your table architecture.then try below two solutions

Solution 1:-

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FacultyDim;
    CREATE TABLE FacultyDim (
        FacultyKey bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        FacultyID bigint NOT NULL,
        FacultyName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (FacultyKey, FacultyID)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Group`; 
    CREATE TABLE `Group` (
        GroupID bigint NOT NULL,
        FacultyID bigint NOT NULL,
        GroupName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (GroupID),
        FOREIGN KEY (FacultyID) REFERENCES FacultyDim(FacultyID,FacultyKey) 
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Solution 2:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FacultyDim;
CREATE TABLE FacultyDim (
    FacultyKey bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FacultyID bigint NOT NULL,
    FacultyName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (FacultyID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Group`; 
CREATE TABLE `Group` (
    GroupID bigint NOT NULL,
    FacultyID bigint NOT NULL,
    GroupName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (GroupID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FacultyID) REFERENCES FacultyDim(FacultyID) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```